# Help with Old exam questions on Bayesian Inference Problem

Tags: self-study, bayesian, inference, posterior

I've been trying to teach myself bayesian inference and I found a question sheet online ---> https://math.mit.edu/~dav/05.dir/ps6.pdf. I was attempting to solve question 4 but I'm not sure the method in doing parts a or b. The formula I have for posterior distribution is giving me the wrong answers. Can anyone tell me how I'd go about solving this, like a general solution that will help me solve questions like this in the future? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to our site, Beth.  It is very important for us to have questions stand by themselves: they cannot rely on material from an external source.  If you would care to quote the key parts of question 4 here and show what wrong answers you are obtaining (and how), that would likely suffice to clarify your post and make it on topic.